# Exception in reading from kafka in spark 2.1.1 when using selectExpr

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am running the default example provided by spark to count words coming from a Kafka stream.

Here is the code I am running:

```java
import scala.Tuple2;

import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FlatMapFunction;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function2;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.PairFunction;
import org.apache.spark.sql.*;
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;


import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function2;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaPairDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaPairReceiverInputDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;

public class JavaWordCount {
    private static final Pattern SPACE = Pattern.compile(" ");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName("JavaWordCount")
                .getOrCreate();
        Dataset<Row> lines = spark
                .readStream()
                .format("kafka")
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
                .option("subscribe", "TutorialTopic")
                .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
                .load();
        lines.selectExpr("CAST key AS STRING", "CAST value AS STRING");
        Dataset<String> words = lines
                .as(Encoders.STRING())
                .flatMap(
                        new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
                            @Override
                            public Iterator<String> call(String x) {
                                return Arrays.asList(x.split(" ")).iterator();
                            }
                        }, Encoders.STRING());
        Dataset<Row> wordCounts = words.groupBy("value").count();
        StreamingQuery query = wordCounts.writeStream()
                .outputMode("complete")
                .format("console")
                .start();

        query.awaitTermination();
    }
}
```

In my pom.xml file I have added the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I submit the code to spark with the following command:

```
./bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.2.2 --class "JavaWordCount" --master local[4] target/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-1.0.jar
```

I get the follwing exception when running :

```
lines.selectExpr("CAST key AS STRING","CAST value AS STRING");
```

Exception:

```
Try to map struct<key:binary,value:binary,topic:string,partition:int,offset:bigint,timestamp:timestamp,timestampType:int> to Tuple1, but failed as the number of fields does not line up.
```

Please help me in resolving this exception.
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is in this line `lines.as(Encoders.STRING())`.

You can change

```
    lines.selectExpr("CAST key AS STRING", "CAST value AS STRING");
    Dataset<String> words = lines
            .as(Encoders.STRING())
```

to

```
    Dataset<String> words = lines.selectExpr("CAST value AS STRING")
            .as(Encoders.STRING())
```

You need to use the return value of `lines.selectExpr`. This method doesn't change `lines` itself. And since you are using `.as(Encoders.STRING())`, I think you only need `value`.